# Matching this string without a lookbehind - Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

We know that JavaScript doesn't support look-behinds. I have been trying to match `CC C` part of the string. However, it matches `C CC C` as well.

The regex should match CC or C only.

String is
`KD IC CC C`

Current Regex:
`(\s*((CC)|(C)))+`

With a look-behind could have been:
`(\s*((CC)|((?>=\s|^)C)))+`

What is an alternative here? I have tried non-capturing groups etc. but didn't work.

Because the function with this regex is used many times, I don't have the option to use other JavaScript functions. The only way to achieve it is by using a regex.

I am also using https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp of NodeJS. Therefore, I might be able to use its additional functionality. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `(?>...)` is atomic group not a look-behind.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html "The construct for positive lookbehind is (?<=text): a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark, "less than" symbol, and an equals sign. Negative lookbehind is written as (?<!text), using an exclamation point instead of an equals sign."

Comment: I would say `/\bCC?\b/`.

Comment: Are you trying to replace those instances? `CC` and `C`, or just match them?

Comment: @KevBot I guess he's dead right after posting his question (-1) :-|

Comment: I'm trying to match them. @procrastinator's comment worked beautifully! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @procrastinator Your comment was the original answer. Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: It's ok, I don't care. Thanks anyway ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the word boundary in this case to achieve the match you are looking for.

```js
var str = 'KD IC CC C';
var found = str.match(/\bcc?\b/gi); // or you can use this: /\bc{1,2}\b/gi

console.log(found);
```

Looks like @procrastinator mentioned the same regex in the comments too.